# R replace the current column (values) with random extreme values, lower than 12.5% and upper than 87.5%

Tags: r

I have a data set with 10 rows (values). Data for example:

```
value <- c(40.557669, 44.436873, 18.541628, 16.524613, 19.34,
       10.07, 17.33, 20.155240, 15.31, 101.23,
       )

data <- data.frame(value)
```

Using quantiles I can select values between the percentages 25%, 50%, 75%.

For example:

```
data$value <- data$value[data$value>=quantile(data$value)[4]]
newvalue <- data$value[data$value>=quantile(data$value)[4]]
data$value <- sample(newvalue, dim(data)[1], replace=T)
```

I would like to replace the current values with random extreme values, lower than 12.5% and upper than 87.5%.

how to do that best?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having issues with your provided dataset, so let's make this reproducible. Start with a `data.frame` with one column, `value`, of 50 random integers:

```
set.seed(4)
df <- data.frame(value = sample(1:100, 50))
```

Get the 12.5% and 87.5% ntiles:

```
ntiles <- quantile(df$value, probs = c(0.125, 0.875))
# ntiles
#  12.5%  87.5% 
# 19.625 85.500
```

Now subset the `data.frame` into the lower extremes and upper extremes:

```
lowers <- subset(df, value < ntiles[1])
uppers <- subset(df, value > ntiles[2])
```

Finally, sample from the combined group of `lowers$value` and `uppers$value`:

```
sample(c(lowers$value, uppers$value), NROW(df), replace = T)
```

I used `NROW(df)` (which will be 50) to grab the same number of records from the original dataset.